# Different time in different sessions

Tags: oracle, timestamp, oracle-sql-developer

I am connecting to same db from 2 different machines using SQL Developer and querying a table which stores timestamp.
But to my surpise the time value returned by query has a gap of one hour on different machine. How is this possible as we are conencting to same DB? and whats the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Probably different timezone is configured on those machines. Check:

```
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM dual;
```

Comment: As this answer suggests, Oracle's concept of time is influenced by the timezone setting of the client computer used to connect to the database. If you use `select systimestamp from dual` you should see that the times -- while in different timezones -- are actually the same.